# Xcode Sqlite update statement only works once

Tags: ios, sqlite, sql-update

I have some code that adds tickets to a database.  I am able to add just fine, but when I try **updating** existing tickets in the database I can only update once and then every update after that fails.  If I restart the app, I can again update once and every update attempt after that fails.  Can someone please help me find whats causing this.  Here is my code that adds/updates to the database.

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_ticketDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

//first I check to see if ticket already exists
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticketnum = \'%@\'", globalData.ticket];
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ticketDB, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
            //Based on if ticket exists, I either update or insert new row
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE tickets SET shippername = \'%@\' WHERE ticketnum = \'%@\'", globalData.shipperName, globalData.ticket];
            }
            else{
                insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO TICKETS (ticketnum, shippername) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\")", globalData.ticket, globalData.shipperName];

            }
        }

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ticketDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Added/Updated");

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add/update ticket to db");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_ticketDB);
    }
```

Comment: Update: Before I update a row in the db I can add new rows just fine, as many as I want.  But after I update one of the rows, I can no longer update or ADD at all after that.  The update statement must be doing something that is causing my db to not be accessible after it is executed once.

Comment: You never finalize your "SELECT" statements, instead you prepare another statement using the very same variable to store it. The old statement doesn't get finalized automatically, it just gets lost in memory and probably that's what's holding "UPDATE" statement from updating such row, because the row is locked by the "SELECT" statement. Just add one more `sqlite3_finalize(statement);` before `sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ticketDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);`

Comment: THANK YOU Googie!  That worked.  I spend way too many hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from Googie's comment:]

You never finalize your "SELECT" statements, instead you prepare another statement using the very same variable to store it. The old statement doesn't get finalized automatically, it just gets lost in memory and probably that's what's holding "UPDATE" statement from updating such row, because the row is locked by the "SELECT" statement.

Just add one more

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

before

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(_ticketDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
```